# MobX store doesn't get updated in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

## What i want to achieve

I have a store object and i want to populate one of it's properties (which is an empty array) with instances of another object. And i want one of my react component automatically updated when part of the mentioned array instance is changed.

## What my problem is

By logging out the value of this constructed store object i can see the change in the browser console, but it doesn't get updated automatically in the react component when its value changed.

So i'd like to get hints, examples of how to implement a solution like this in general.

---

### Details

#### My project

I want to create a MobX store called **Session** which would store everything my react webapp needs.
This webapp would be a document handling tool, so after creating new or loading existing documents i want to add the **Document** object to the **Session** (into an object array called **documents**).
Some more details: a **Document** consists of one or more **section**. So using a WYSIWYG editor i add its content to the given section every time it's content changes.

#### Problem

I can add a new **Document** to the **Session**, i can update section as well(I can log out the value of a section in console), but using the **Session** reference to this document and section in a react component it doesnt update its state when section value is changed.
To my understanding in my example the reference of a **Document** is not changed when the value of a section is changed and hence it doesn't trigger MobX to react.

#### What i found so far

I started to dig in the deep, dark web and found [this](https://blog.pixelingene.com/2016/10/effective-mobx-patterns-part-1/) article.
So i started getting excited since *asStructure* (or *asMap*) seemed to solve this issue, but it looks like *asStructure* in MobX is deprecated.
Then i found this [issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/751) thread, where a thing called *observable.structurallyCompare* is mentioned. But again i found nothing about this in MobX documentation so im puzzled how to implement it.

So im stuck again and have no idea how to solve this problem.

#### Code excerpts from my project

This is how i reference to the mentioned Session value in the main react component:

```
import userSession from '../client/Session';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

@observer class App extends React.Component {
...

render() {

  return (
    ...
    <div>{JSON.stringify(userSession.documents[0].content.sections)}</div>

  ...
```

This is how i update the section in the editor react component:

```
import userSession from '../../client/Session';
...

handleChange(value,arg2,arg3,arg4) {
  this.setState({ content: value, delta: arg4.getHTML()});
  userSession.documents[0].updateSectionContent(this.props.id, this.state.delta);
  }
}

...
```

Session.js excerpt:

```
class Session {
  constructor(){
    extendObservable(this, {
      user: {
      },
      layout: {
      },
      documents: []
    })

    //current hack to add an empty Document to Session
    this.documents.push(new Document());
  }

  //yadayadayada...

  @action addNewSection() {
    userSession.documents[0].content.sections.push({
            type: "editor",
            id: userSession.documents[0].getNextSectionID(),
            editable: true,
            content: "",
            placeholder: "type here to add new section..."
    });
  }
}

var userSession = window.userSession = new Session();
export default userSession;
```

Document.js

```
import {extendObservable, computed, action} from "mobx";
import userSession from "./Session";

class Document {
  constructor(doc = null) {
    if (doc == null) {
      console.log("doc - no init value provided");
      extendObservable(this,{
        labels: {
          title: "title",
          description: "description",
          owners: ["guest"]
        },
        content: {
          sections: [
            {
              type: "editor",
              id: "sec1",
              editable: true,
              placeholder: "this is where the magic happens"
            },
          ]
        }
      })

    } else {
      console.log("doc - init values provided: ");
      extendObservable(this,{
        labels: doc.labels,
        content: doc.content
      });
    }
  }

  getNextSectionID(){
    return `sec${this.content.sections.length}`;
  }

  @action updateSectionContent(sectionID, delta) {
    console.log("doc - looking for section " + sectionID + " to update with this: " + delta);
    let index = this.content.sections.findIndex(
      section => section.id === sectionID
    );
    userSession.documents[0].content.sections[index].content = delta;

  }
}

export default Document;
```

Ps.: atm moment i don't remember why i made **Document** properties observable, but for some reason it was necessary.

Comment: The pattern you're using is not the "standard" Mobx style with decorators, so you're going to have a hard time getting help with your approach (and reading your own code). 

It would be great if you switched to that style, and cut out all of the descriptions that don't directly relate to your question. What is the expected behavior, and what is the behavior that you are actually seeing?

Comment: I emphasized the sections with headers and added a simple summary at the beginning. I also think all the details necessary/can be useful to understand my problem. As i remember i choose this solution because this way it's easier to have all this stuff in the constructor. This is also "standard" solution: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html

Comment: No, it isn't standard, extendObservable only exists so that observable properties can be added dynamically to an object. Since you don't need to add observable properties dynamically, you shouldn't use it.

You shouldn't be using a constructor either. See https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html

Comment: Thanks for your efforts trying to educate me on proper application of standard mobx features. 1st, im **going to** add properties dynamically later, maybe that's why i wanted to try this out in the constructor (cant find the corresponding SO thread, but i copied a solution from here). And what is constructor for if not for setting initial values of an object? 2nd, maybe it's my lack of understanding mobx concepts, but found nothing relevant on the pitfalls page. What are you referring to? 3rd, i would really appreciate if you could give some recommendation on the actual problem i have. Thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are implementing `mobx` with React the incorrect way. To make it more comprehensible, I suggest you look into the implementation of the HOC `observer` that `mobx-react` provide.

Basically, what this HOC does is to wrap your component inside another React component that implement `shouldComponentUpdate` that check when the **props** referred inside `render` function change, and trigger the re-render. To make React component reactive to change in `mobx` store, you need to pass the store data to them as `props`, either in React traditional way, or via the `inject` HOC that `mobx-react` provide.

The problem while your code does not react to change in the store is because you import the store and use them directly inside your component, `mobx-react` cannot detect change that way.

To make it reactive, instead of import it and use it directly in your `App` component, you can pass the store as a prop as follow:

```
@observer 
class App extends React.Component {
...

   render() {

     return (
     ...
       <div>{this.props.sections}</div>

     ...);
    }
}
```

Then pass the store to `App` when it's used:

```
<App sections={userSession.documents[0].content.sections} />
```

You can also have a look at how to use `inject` here: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react.

An just a suggestion: before jumping directly on some `best pattern`, try to stick with the basic, standard way that library author recommend and understand how it works first, you can consider other option after you got the core idea.

Comment: Ok, i got sick, but im back. I already did what you recommended, but it still doesnt get updated. The problem is somewhere with the store and the other object which is assigned to one of the stores property which is an array. I add the object to the store but when the object properties updated it doesn't trigger update in the store.